# Gutenberg registerFormatType with Multiple Classes

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm adding a button to Gutenbergs RichTextToolbar with a plugin I created, but I cannot figure out how to add mulitple classes to the tag/span I create.

```
( function( wp ) {
    var MyCustomButton = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'Sample output',
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
            title: 'Sample output',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'classname another-classname',  //this line needs the help - works as just 'classname' no spaces but can only wrap with one class then
            edit: MyCustomButton,
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

Console error says:

> A class name must begin with a letter, followed by any number of
>   hyphens, letters, or numbers.

So the space is creating the error, but how do I add 2 classes to this function? I've also tried the following which doesn't work.

```
className: {'has-primary-color has-text-color'},
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component - you can use template literals, or you can install `classnames`.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the registerFormatType function [source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/rich-text/src/register-format-type.js), only letters, numbers, "_" and "-" are allowed in the class name.

```
if ( ! /^[_a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/.test( settings.className ) ) {
    window.console.error(
        'A class name must begin with a letter, followed by any number of 
         hyphens, letters, or numbers.'
    );
    return;
}
```

So you cannot separate two class names with a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra classes in the options section of toggleFormat. The className specified in the registerFormatType is used to distinguish between different formats so needs to be one class.

In your example:

```
( function( wp ) {
    var MyCustomButton = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'Sample output',
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        {
                            type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output',
                            attributes: {
                                class: 'another-classname'
                            }
                        }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
            title: 'Sample output',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'classname', 
            edit: MyCustomButton,
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```